# How do I burn a DVD ISO from a MacBook?

Tags: macbook-pro, dvd-burning

The MacBook Air can share DVD drives on other Macs. For reading disks this works great. However, I want to burn an ISO to the drive. The drive doesn't show up in Disk Utility. Is it possible to burn ISOs onto a shared drive from a MacBook Air?

Comment: Good question! Just as a side note - in Lion it should be just as easy to copy the media using Lion's AirDrop and then use the other Mac to burn the DVD.

Comment: @gentmatt you should upvote the question if you think its good :) +1 from me

Comment: I know. And I really want to! But I've already used my 40 votes today because of all the newcomers! There are so many of them - I really thought that this was spam :D. I feel so dumb. I'll up vote tomorrow, promise!

Comment: Ask Different was advertised on tuaw.com a few days ago. That'll be the source of the newcomers. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try to insert a empty disk into your mac. Then, share it with you MacBook Air. Now, you should have a new DVD-Icon in the finder sidebar.

It should now show up in the Disk Utility tool!

Or:

**Right-Click** on the ISO-Image, and click **Burn on CD/DVD** after you "connected" the empty CD/DVD to you MacBook Air via DVD-Sharing.